# Accessing rails private/protected methods through javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, private-methods

I know I can access public controller actions by doing something like this with jquery:

```
$("#stuff").load("/controller/action");
```

But how do I access the private/protected actions in a controller using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an action in the controller file which will call your private or protected action. A direct call is not possible.